# missing apk with visual studio 2015 and Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using VS 2015 and the Cordova Tools update 2 for VS 2015.
I build my project in Debug mode, but there's no generated apk in any folder.

The build succeeds.

Same for Release builds..

This started happening since I installed the Update 2 pack.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you still having problems?  Here are a few approaches that have worked to resolve issues with VS2015:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

devenv.exe /updateconfiguration & then /clearcache?
devenv.exe /resetuserdata -- clears all user data from VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

Same Issue, but in reléase mode whit keystore for sign apk in adroid.

Build succeds but not apk or objets in build folder.

Answer (score 0):

[visual studio / apache cordova - Build is successful - But no apk is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431890/visual-studio-apache-cordova-build-is-successful-but-no-apk-is-generated)

Answer 1

```
1) In command line check the cli version: cordova -v
2) Double-click config.xml and select "Platforms" tab. There enter the Cordova CLI version.
```