# visual studio / apache cordova - Build is successful - But no apk is generated

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

[Apache Cordova - Visual Studio 2015 - Unable to build signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428638/apache-cordova-visual-studio-2015-unable-to-build-signed-apk/34431749#34431749)

In the above link, I asked a question. I was not able to generate a signed apk.
Then, I found that i need to enter the **keystore** in **build.json** file.

After that, i got some other error. So, I updated my nodejs version to 5.3.0
Now,

```
begin snippet: js hide: false -->

 language: lang-html -->

     Build started: Project: SignedTest, Configuration: Release Android ------
     Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 5.3.0 (ia32) and npm.
     Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
    Name from source package.json: vs-tac
     Version from source package.json: 1.0.16
    Package already installed globally at correct version.
     Cordova tools 5.3.3 already installed.
     Build Settings:
     Build Settings:
       platformConfigurationBldDir: E:\Visual Studio 2015\SignedTest\SignedTest\bld\Android\Release
       platformConfigurationBinDir: E:\Visual Studio 2015\SignedTest\SignedTest\bin\Android\Release
       buildCommand: build
        platform: Android
       cordovaPlatform: android
       configuration: Release
       cordovaConfiguration: Release
        projectName: SignedTest
       projectSourceDir: E:\Visual Studio 2015\SignedTest\SignedTest
        npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Mahesh\AppData\Roaming\npm
       buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
       language: en-US
       changeList.changedFilesIos: bower.json,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\index.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\ja\README.md,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\NOTICE,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\android\WhitelistPlugin.java,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\css\index.css,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\it\README.md,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\de\README.md,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\whitelist.js,plugins\fetch.json,config.xml,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\pl\README.md,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\fr\README.md,package.json,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\plugin.xml,build.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\zh\README.md,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\package.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\CONTRIBUTING.md,res\native\android\ant.properties,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\LICENSE,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\ko\README.md,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\RELEASENOTES.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\doc\es\README.md,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\README.md,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png
       changeList.deletedFilesIos:
        changeList.addedPluginsIos:
       changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
        changeList.addedPlugins:
        changeList.deletedPlugins:
   Platform android already exists
     Copying native files from E:\Visual Studio 2015\SignedTest\SignedTest\res\native\android to platforms\android
    Copied E:\Visual Studio 2015\SignedTest\SignedTest\res\native\android\ant.properties to platforms\android\ant.properties
     Done copying native files to platforms\android
    Updating plugins
     Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.2.0
     Currently installed dependent plugins:
    Currently configured plugins:
     Preparing platform: android
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It says build is successful but i am not seeing any apk in bin/android/release and platform/android/build

Comment: Can you go into platforms/android folder and run gradlew.bat directly ? What output do you get ? 

Looks like the prepare happened, but for some reason, the actual android build did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Did following:

```
1) In command line check the cli version: cordova -v
2) Double-click config.xml and select "Platforms" tab. There enter the Cordova CLI version.
```